# ¿Cómo pasar un OAuth2 token de App Engine a Google Picker?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth2

Tengo una app construido con ***App Engine*** y el usuario ingresa con OAuth2. 
En el servidor todo funciona con el token que tengo y quiero usar el mismo token para la autorización de ***Google Picker*** pero obtengo una respuesta de **error 401**, de no autorizado. Incluiyo en el scope todo lo necesario para usar la vista que requiero. También tengo el Picker API habilitada.

**Pregunto :**

¿Se puede usar el mismo token en el cliente?  O sea ¿es seguro? ¿También hay otras alternativas de ***Google Picker***? Quiero evitar que el usuario apruebe dos veces el OAuth2.

Comment: Si esta habilitada la API en la consola de app engine?

Comment: Si claro. Como mencioné el token si trabaja en el servidor. Pero gracias por su respuesta. Y tambien el Picker esta habilitada.  Cuando pongo una vista que no necesita autorizacion como Image Search, todo chevere, pero usando el token con Photos View, entonce todo a la quiebra.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tengo que disculparme. No mencione que estaba programando con GWT y usando la liberia GWT-google-picker.  A traves de muchos intentos veo que el problema era con Gwt-Ajaxloader. Creo que tiene una manera antigua de llamar a los apis.
Para solucionar mi problema solo tuve que escribir el html :

```
 <!--  The Following proves that picker works with oAuth2 -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('picker');
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
```

Una vez llamado y el objeto 'picker' esta disponible para usar con el gwt-google-picker y el bendito token ya sirve.

**Edit**
This might not be the fix so I won't mark it as correct .... But please make sure to add the domain to the allow https:// from list with wild cards to the browser key. This might have been the error.
**Coreccion **
El problema no era con la librería sino con el hecho que nu había autorizado el uso de clave con el domain...por lo tanto mi respuesta no está correcta.